# ios : Displaying a simple 3D model with GLEssentials sample code

Tags: ios, opengl-es

My goal is to display a simple 3D model and apply a texture on it.

I've downloaded the GLEssentials [ios sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010104-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to learn how to develop this (i'm new in ios OpenGL-ES API)

But the example model is a .model file, which I never heard about and which never appear in [model bank websites](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-excellent-free-3d-model-websites/).

1. What is this kind of file?
2. is the sample code compatible with other common model types (.obj, .c2d, .3ds)?
3. is it a good idea to start from this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this question:

- [How to convert Blender blend (or obj) file to Qualcom Vuforia .h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508930/how-to-convert-blender-blend-or-obj-file-to-qualcom-vuforia-h-file/14509789#14509789)

In my answer, I describe a script and accompanying Xcode project that converts .obj/.mtl files to header files suitable for OpenGL ES on iOS [[link]](https://github.com/ricardo-rendoncepeda/mtl2opengl).

In response to your questions:

1. I believe the .model file is only appropriate for the sample project and is a proprietary Apple extension. It most likely contains simple data such as vertex positions.
2. I think you'd struggle to fit other model types into the sample code, which is very complex for OpenGL ES beginners. You might want to have a look at .pod files on Cocos2D [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5077). I've seen and heard great things about it.
3. I wouldn't recommend it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been on the cocos2D site & doc, which seems to be great, but... I don't want to make a game, but just display some models on `UIView`. Cocos2D seems to be a bit too huge for my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344430/opengles-display-human-face-in-iphone can you please have a look at this link and help me over this. I also need some documentation for your code.